# Get stains out of the sink vs Remove stains from the sink?

Tags: american-english

Are both of these phrases grammatically correct?

> I need to get those stains **out of** the sink.
>
> I need to remove those stains **from** the sink.

Answer (score 2):

Short and sweet answer: Yes, and both make sense semantically to me.

Slightly longer answer: To me, to **get stains out of** something implies that the stains might be a bit tougher, and more difficult to remove.